# Need help understanding this WP Query

Tags: wp-query, themes

So I have this theme where there is an about section that is showing in the customizer, but there isn't a specific post type on the admin page that adds post to this section.

How do I add post to the about section with the template code stated below.

```
if(isset($xt_corporate_lite_opt['xt_about_page']) && 
$xt_corporate_lite_opt['xt_about_page'] != '') {
    $xt_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'page_id' => $xt_corporate_lite_opt['xt_about_page']
    ));
    if ($xt_query->have_posts()) {
        while ($xt_query->have_posts()) {
            $xt_query->the_post();
            the_content();
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: It's a single page of the `page` post type, the query is loading that page by its `page_id`.

Comment: thanks for the reply milo :). sorry for my ignorance, I am really new to this. How then do I add posts to this page so that the loop will output them?

Comment: Pages and posts are two seperate *types* of data - you don't tend to display one inside the other. The above code is displaying a particular page. To modify this page, you'll likely need to visit the "Pages" section in the Dashboard, find the corresponding page, and edit it there. If you cannot find the page, this may be a theme-specific issue, in which case you should pose your question in the official support channels for your theme.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code to show only post.

```
if(isset($xt_corporate_lite_opt['xt_about_page']) && $xt_corporate_lite_opt['xt_about_page'] != '') {
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post');
    $xt_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($xt_query->have_posts()) {
        while ($xt_query->have_posts()) {
            $xt_query->the_post();
            the_content();
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

if you have any doubt in WP_Query.
then you could check this link in detail.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your code snippet is running on a portion of the page, rather then being used to override the entire page content you'll want to change the WP_Query arguments.

To show a list of posts on that page: `post_type => 'post'`
To show all posts on that page: `posts_per_page => -1`
To limit the number of posts on that page to 5: `posts_per_page => 5`

So that would look something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post', // only show posts in this query
    'posts_per_page' => 5, // only show 5 posts. Leave this blank to have the query results set by your website settings instead
);
```

Also, make sure that your query ends with `wp_reset_query` to restore the $wp_query variable and all data back to the original query.

So your full function would look something like this:

```
if(isset($xt_corporate_lite_opt['xt_about_page']) && $xt_corporate_lite_opt['xt_about_page'] != '') {
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'post',
        // Any extra arguments you want here that WP_Query will take
    );
    $xt_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($xt_query->have_posts()) {
        while ($xt_query->have_posts()) {
            $xt_query->the_post();
            the_content();
        }
        wp_reset_query(); // put this right after the while loop or after you're sure you are done using those variables (like pagination)
    }
}
```

`wp_reset_postdata()` is similar to `wp_reset_query()` but will only restore the $post variable NOT the the full query. You could probably use either in this situation ;)

**Helpful Documentation:**

1. wp_reset_query: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query
2. wp_reset_postdata: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata
3. WP_Query: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query (you probably have already looked at this a bit, but it's very handy to know everything you can get with WP_Query. It's a very very powerful tool!)